# Trouble sharing payment method to sub-account in stripe

Tags: stripe-payments

Issue: I cannot share acss_debit to any of my connected accounts.

Question: How can I add acss_debit to a connected account, cause my use case requires I use acss_debit for PADS in Canada?

`const paymentMethod = await stripe.paymentMethods.create({ customer: 'cus_M9DwnCRdIYRW16', payment_method: 'pm_1LSJqqIh9VOrzIlk5qKZUrwm', // type: acss_debit },  { stripeAccount: 'acct_1LSK7mRK0p6psgP0', });`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, cloning payment methods are not supported for acss_debit. Only types **card** or **us_bank_account** are supported:

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#cloning-payment-methods

Comment: What do you suggest I do instead because I need pads for the transactions